# how to make wordpress generate specific html element with class name I wish

Tags: wordpress

So basically I am trying to add `ClassName` to a `Home` link in navigation bar on top of page.

Where to find this PHP generating code? Example appreciated.

Many many thanks.

Comment: you'll have to give some code examples. But in general, wordpress does all manner of html emitting at every stage of the page render (in addition to the markup in your theme). To determine the correction function that does the outputting, the wp codex is pretty thorough. Once you determine the correct code, either override it in your theme's function.php, or use something like the add_filter function to alter some particular output. But, as i noted, post some specific code if you want some help ;) cheers

Comment: thanks for writing back. i am using wordpress theme `twentyeleven`, default one. just trying to add custom class name to `home` link in nav bar on top of page. sorry that i don't have any code to offer yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think its possible to add custom class to menu generated by `wp_nav_menu` function at the moment.

However you can create a custom Menu @ `Dashboard > Appearance > Menu` and set it as `Primary Menu`.

After which you can add the "Home" link as custom menu item, which in turn will generate unique id for home link and each of the menu item of the format "`menu-item-<menu_item_id>`" and classes of the format "`menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom [current-menu-item] [current_page_item] menu-item-home menu-item-<menu_item_id>`".

(`<menu_item_id>` - is some no. and class within [ ] is optional.)

You can use the id or one of the classes or both, to do what you want with the CSS or javascript.

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I have found out about that one too.

Comment: Please do share the solution so it can be useful for others.